# Android - Free space for external storage not displaying correctly

Tags: java, android, storage

It goes like this: I'm developing an application that records chunks of video. When it detects that the free space has fallen under a certain treshold, it tries to delete old videos until the free amount of storage exceeds the threshold. If free storage falls under another threshold, lower than the first one, the app stops recording and displays a dialog informing about the lack of storage.

I have written a class that should help with these storage issues:

```
package net.ghetu.dasheye;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Vector;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;

class StorageManager extends Thread {

    private static final String TAG = "StorageManager";

    private static File mediaStorageDir = new File(
            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "DashEyeApp");
    private static long totalSpace = mediaStorageDir.getTotalSpace();
    private static long full99 = (long) (0.01 * totalSpace);
    private static long full97 = (long) (0.03 * totalSpace);
    private boolean isStopped = false;
    private Vector<VideoItem> directoryEntries = null;

    private GlobalState mAppState;
    private PreviewService mPreviewService;

    public void setStopped() {
        isStopped = true;
    }

    public StorageManager(Context appState, PreviewService previewService) {
        mAppState = (GlobalState) appState;
        mPreviewService = previewService;
    }

    public static boolean hasRunOutOufSpace() {
        long freeSpace = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getFreeSpace();
        if (freeSpace <= full99)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public static boolean hasLowSpace() {
        long freeSpace = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                "DashEyeApp").getFreeSpace();
        Log.d(TAG,
                "Free space: "
                        + Long.toString((long) (freeSpace / (1024 * 1024)))
                        + "MB");
        if (freeSpace <= full97)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();
        while (!isStopped) {
            if (hasLowSpace()) {
                if (hasRunOutOufSpace()) {
                    if (mPreviewService != null) {
                        if (mAppState.isRecording()) {
                            mPreviewService.stopRecording();
                            mPreviewService.displayStorageDialog();
                            isStopped = true;
                        } else {
                            mPreviewService.displayStorageDialog();
                            isStopped = true;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    if (mAppState.detectLoopModeActive()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Making space ...");

                        directoryEntries = getAllVideos();
                        Log.d(TAG,     Integer.toString(directoryEntries.size()));

                        if (directoryEntries.size() > 1) {

                            directoryEntries.get(directoryEntries.size() - 1)
                                    .getmFile().delete();
                            directoryEntries
                                    .remove(directoryEntries.size() - 1);

                        }
                        directoryEntries.clear();
                    }
                }
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private Vector<VideoItem> getAllVideos() {
        Vector<VideoItem> directoryEntries = new Vector<VideoItem>();
        File files[] = mediaStorageDir.listFiles();
        if (files != null) {
            if (files.length > 0) {
                for (File file : files) {
                    if (VideoDetector.isVideo(file))
                        directoryEntries.add(new VideoItem(file));
                }

                Collections.sort(directoryEntries,
                        VideoItem.VideoDateComparatorDesc);
            }
        }    

        files = null;
        Log.d(TAG,
                "Fetching files: " + directoryEntries.size() + " files US: "
                        + mediaStorageDir.getUsableSpace() + " FS: "
                        + mediaStorageDir.getFreeSpace());
        return directoryEntries;
    }
}
```

My class, however, does not help me. What happens is: videos get deleted but hasLowSpace() still returns true. I. e.

```
long freeSpace = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                "DashEyeApp").getFreeSpace();
```

Does not take into account the free space gained by deleting a video. Below, a sample of the log:

```
03-11 00:19:54.995: D/StorageManager(2863): Free space: 236MB
03-11 00:19:54.995: D/StorageManager(2863): Making space ...
03-11 00:19:55.015: D/StorageManager(2863): Fetching files: 3 files US: 248168448 FS: 248168448
03-11 00:19:55.015: D/StorageManager(2863): 3
03-11 00:20:00.015: D/StorageManager(2863): Free space: 230MB
03-11 00:20:00.015: D/StorageManager(2863): Making space ...
03-11 00:20:00.030: D/StorageManager(2863): Fetching files: 2 files US: 242081792 FS: 242081792
03-11 00:20:00.030: D/StorageManager(2863): 2
```

**Notice that free space decreases while the number of videos in the folder also decreases.**

Any ideas why this might be? At this point I'm desperate and willing to try everything. Experiencing this bug in Android 4.4.4 on a Samsung Galaxy i9305. Had the same problem on a Galaxy S1 GT-i9000 with a custom Android 4.4.4 ROM.

Comment: Hm, not displaying correctly? then how much free space does your phone has if it shown 230MB?

Comment: It should have more. If you check out the log, it first has 236MB with 3 files and after deleting one file it has less than that (230MB). Deleting files should free up space, though it looks like it doesn't.

Comment: why Long.toString? why you dont use String.valueOf?

Comment: Perhaps I have not been clear: the problem is that getFreeSpace() returns wrong values.

Answer (score 1):

As android developer say "The getFreeSpace method returns the number of bytes potentially available to root". So you cannot use it without run as root. So i have a method to calculate the available block bytes.

```
public static float megabytesAvailable(File f) {
    StatFs stat = new StatFs(f.getPath());
    long bytesAvailable = (long)stat.getBlockSizeLong() * (long)stat.getAvailableBlocksLong();
    return bytesAvailable / (1024.f * 1024.f);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Android Doc says that getFreeSpace() method returns the number of bytes potentially available to root, while getUsableSpace() returns the number of free bytes available to non-root users.

You can have a try to getUsableSpace().